# Remove space between span-s

Tags: html, css, sass

I want to remove this space to make `<span>`-s closer, but there is no any margin or padding that could add more space between them.

[image]

```html
<!-- HTML -->
<div class="service-container" id="logo-title-service-container">
    <span class="logo-text" id="logo-title">company name</span><br>
    <span class="logo-text" id="logo-subtitle">This is a subtitle</span>
</div>
```

**Sass**

```
// Sass
#logo-title-service-container
    text-align: left
    padding-left: 10px
    #logo-title
        font-size: 18px
    #logo-subtitle
        padding-top: -5px
        font-size: 12px
```

How can I remove the space between them?

Comment: margin-top instead of padding-top

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should remove the 'br' element first.

then make the display of title and subtitle **block** or as i did here make the parent display flex and flex-direction to column to make it work.

```css
#logo-service-container {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 15px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

#logo-main {
  width: 26px;
  height: 26px;
}

#logo-title-service-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

#logo-title {
  font-size: 18px;
}

#logo-subtitle {
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<div class="sidebar" id="left-sidebar">
  <div class="service-container" id="logo-service-container">
    <img id="logo-main" src="resources/images/icons/logo.svg" alt="logo">
    <div class="service-container" id="logo-title-service-container">
      <span class="logo-text" id="logo-title">company name</span>
      <span class="logo-text" id="logo-subtitle">This is a subtitle</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You should try to avoid `<br>`

replace the span with div

```
<div class="sidebar" id="left-sidebar">
  <div class="service-container" id="logo-service-container">
    <img id="logo-main" src="resources/images/icons/logo.svg" alt="logo">
    <div class="service-container" id="logo-title-service-container">
      <div class="logo-text" id="logo-title">company name</div>
      <div class="logo-text" id="logo-subtitle">This is a subtitle</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

SASS:

```
#logo-service-container
  width: 100%
  text-align: center
  padding-top: 15px
  display: flex
  align-items: center
  justify-content: center
  #logo-main
    $size: 26px
    width: $size
    height: $size
  #logo-title-service-container
    text-align: left
    padding-left: 10px
    #logo-title
      font-size: 18px
    #logo-subtitle
      padding-top: -5px
      font-size: 12px
```